# Continuous random sampling with replacement.

Tags: probability-theory, integration, permutations, sampling

Construct a set $s\subseteq[0,1]$ by sampling points in $[0,1]$ with uniform probability density $x\leq1$ so that $|s|=x$. Interpret this as a sampling frame during which data is captured. Now, consider a decreasing function $f(t)$ with domain $[0,1]$. One can calculate the expected integral sum of the observed values of $f(t)$ (where the expectation is over every possible permutation of $s$) as $$\int_0^{1}\!x f(t)\,dt.$$

Now, fix a truncation point $T\in\mathbb{N}$ and construct a new, periodic, function $g(t)$ as follows: $$g(t)=f(t)$$ if $t<1/T$, and $$g(t)=g[t-(1/T)]$$ if $t\geq 1/T$. How can one calculate the expected integral sum of the unique observed values of $g(t)$ given $s\subseteq[0,1]$?

I had thought that one could approach this problem by saying that repeating the first $1/T$ seconds of signal $f$ $T$ times was equivalent to supposing that $s\subseteq[0,1/T]$ with the density of each point in $s$ being $T\min\{x,1/T\}$. The integral would then be
$$\int_0^{1/T}\!T\min\{x,1/T\} f(t)\,dt.$$

Suppose $x=1/T$. The above integral then becomes $$\int_0^{1/T}\!f(t)\,dt,$$ which corresponds to observing $f(t)$ at every point in $[0,1/T]$ with probability 1. This seems counterintuitive because there are many permutations of $s$ (such as $s=[0,1/2T]\cup[1/T,3/2T]$) in which some positive measure of $f(t)$ are observed more than once.

Comment: I wonder what could be a mathematical model the first sentence would describe. You might want to expand on that.

Comment: @Did Here's one contrived rationalisation: imagine a hotel with two lounges. People wander randomly back and forth between the two lounges spending total time $x=1/2$ in each. A comedian performs in one of the lounges and has a stock of jokes $[0,1]$. They can be ordered so that his best joke has quality $f(0)$ and the worst $f(1)$. People only enjoy a joke the first time they hear it. If he repeats his $1/T$ best jokes, what is the expected total value of the comedy show for a given hotel guest?

Comment: In other words you suggest that one should forget the part about choosing $s\subset[0,1]$? If this is so, you might want to rewrite the question.

Comment: @Did I don't suggest we forget about that part. It's hard to say that we want to calculate the expectation over all possible $s$ if $s$ is not defined.

Comment: Then we are back at square one: how to choose $s$ randomly?

Comment: @Did Is there a problem with saying each $a\in[0,1]$ is in $s$ with probability $x$ and not in $s$ with probability $1-x$? Quite possibly, there is a better way of framing the whole question, but I am still trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Indeed "there is a problem". To begin with, the resulting set $s$ would not be measurable hence $|s|$ would not exist.

Comment: @Did Thanks, I see that now. I will think about reformulating the question in a way that makes sense.